# Send exception for UNIQUE constraint to UI in .NET core

Tags: sql, .net, linq, unique

When a unique constraint exception occurs, how do I message the UI in .NET Core; I want to return JSON, not MVC/Razor approach.

Comment: What you want to do actually?
Trying to log errors from sql?
Put your sql statements in a try-catch block and in catch block parse error to json.

Comment: Ok, so inside my dBContext file Im using LINQ/FluentAPI, and  I have:                                                                       modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .HasAlternateKey(p => p.ProductName);

Comment: And my controller file has:                                                                         
    try
            {
                
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                
            }                                                                                                                      A potential catch could be DbUpdateException, but neither get triggered when the UNIQUE contraint prevents the duplicate from being written into the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have been looking at my article [Catching Bad Data in Entity Framework](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/catching-bad-data-in-entity-framework/). In there I describe a way to catch a SQL error and turn it into a validation error for EF Core.

**UPDATE**

In answer to your follow on questions I can point you to the code associated with the book I am writing, [Entity Framework Core in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/entity-framework-core-in-action?a_aid=su4utaraxuTre8tuthup&a_bid=4cef27ce). In this I built a method called `SaveChangesSqlCheck`, which contains the code to check for sql errors. You would use this method instead of calling `SaveChanges`, and it will return a `ValidationResult`.

My book has associated [git repository](https://github.com/JonPSmith/EfCoreInAction) where I have unit tests for just about everything I show in the book. Below are links to a unit test to see how you call `SaveChangesSqlCheck`, and then the `SaveChangesSqlCheck` code itself.

- Unit test: https://github.com/JonPSmith/EfCoreInAction/blob/Chapter10/Test/UnitTests/DataLayer/Ch10_CatchSqlError.cs#L59-L89
- The `SaveChangesSqlCheck` code: https://github.com/JonPSmith/EfCoreInAction/blob/Chapter10/DataLayer/EfCode/SaveChangesSqlCheck.cs
- The method that catches the Unique error: https://github.com/JonPSmith/EfCoreInAction/blob/Chapter10/DataLayer/EfCode/SqlErrorFormatters.cs

Note: you need to format the unique constraint name in a special way - see https://github.com/JonPSmith/EfCoreInAction/blob/Chapter10/Test/Chapter10Listings/EfCode/Configuration/MyUniqueConfig.cs for an example.

---

If you plan to use the code shown in the article then all you need to do is use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errors)` to turn that into json. I have included some code so you can see what the json output would look like.

```
var error = new ValidationResult("error message");
var jsonList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(error,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented });
```

The json output of this would be

```
{
   "MemberNames": [],
   "ErrorMessage": "error message"
}
```

I hope that helps.